# Center of Instantaneous velocity in two degree of freedom problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I have a problem like this
[image]

I have two DoF where the force F is acting on the *car* and another force could be acting on the coordinate $q_1$. The force acting on $q_2$, the coordinate of the car will give me some velocity $v_B$ and the force acting on the body C will give me $v_C$. My issue is computing the angular velocity of body C. Can someone explain to me which one of the following is correct, and why. (I have a no slip condition between C and B).

The angular velocity $\omega$ is like this
[image]

And that is because we only care about $\dot{q}_1$ relative to the *car* which we suppose to have zero velocity. Or is the second case, where we actually care about the velocity of the car and we measure everything relative to the ground thing.

[image]

I would like to understand the principle why? The idea is that I will need to ultimately calculate the kinetic energies of each component so, hence body C is under general planar motion so I will need to account for the rotation.

$$ E_{K_C} = \frac{1}{2}\,m_C\,\dot{q}_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}\,I_C\,\omega^2 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is never valid. Even when considering the *relative* motion of *C* to *B* with the point of contact not moving, then center of *C* should move with $v_C -v_B$ instead of $v_C$.

The correct picture is the second one. The disk *C* is specified to have velocity $v_C$ at its center, and $v_B$ at the contact point, and the only way to achieve this is through the instant center you drew. Actually the second sketch is very descriptive (to me). No further explanation is needed from there.

<sub>Also note that the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation) is pretty good describing instant centers.</sub>